# Ubuntu server starts as a black screen

Tags: boot, timeout

I just converted ubuntu desktop 14.04 to ubuntu server using these steps:

```
sudo service lightdm stop

sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo tasksel install server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-server linux-image-server
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get purge firefox

sudo ifconfig eth0 up   
sudo dhclient eth0

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I installed Sentora. When I rebooted at the end of that, I got a black screen for about one minute, then an underscore in the top left corner for a couple seconds and then the terminal started. I feel like there's something messed up in grub where it's still trying to start lightdm and that eventually times out and it goes to terminal. Does anyone know how I could check that and fix the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. It sounds like it's fine.

Comment: I guess it takes more like 2-3 minutes to get to the terminal it just seems excessive.

Comment: You're right, it is a bit much. You can try `sudo apt-get remove unity-*`, __But please make sure it's not installing anything essential__.

Comment: wouldn't an `apt-get autoremove` take care of any stragglers like that?

Comment: Interesting, I was also having to manually start my network adapter every time so I took a peak in that file and noticed that I had borked it. Fixing that fixed my boot time.

Comment: Only unused dependencies, which wouldn't be what's getting in your way.

Comment: Well there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing my interface file fixed the problem.

I had it set up as

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.34
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 192.168.1.1
     broadcast 192.168.1.255
     gateway 192.168.1.1
```

The problem was fixed by adding `eth0` to the end of the first line.